# Не прогружаются картинки на хосте

Tags: html, css, laravel, img

не прогружаются картинки на удаленном хосте,на локальном все работает.Может ошибка в путях?

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
```

Вставляла через урл картинки с фотохостинга,но и там не всегда работает

Comment: Может. А может и нет.

Comment: <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="100">

Answer (score 1):

Если хранишь картинки на хостинге в папке public, можешь выводить так:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('routeName') }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="" width="150" height="100">
</a>
```